# Change text size in colorkey in heatmap.2

Tags: r, heatmap

I want to change text size in the colorkey in heatmap.2, for all text in the color key, title, x axis and y axis, xlab and ylab. how do I do this? Thanks!

```
Example
 # load package
    library("gplots")
    
    # make matrix
    mat <- matrix(rnorm(1200), ncol=6)
    
    # heatmap with the defaults parameters
    heatmap.2(x=mat)
    
    heatmap.2(x=mat, keysize=0.8,key.xlab="Test")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `cexRow, cexCol` parameters.

For my 15.6 inches screen looks nice this:

```
library(gplots)

dev.new()

mat <- matrix(rnorm(1200), ncol=6)

heatmap.2(x=mat)

heatmap.2(x=mat, keysize=0.8, key.xlab="Test", cexRow = 1, cexCol = 1.5)
```

[image]